# systemVerilog - How can I verify if integer member is null?

Tags: null, system-verilog

I have the following function:

```
   function void my_randomize_int(int seed, inout int mem, int min, int max); 
      if(max == null) begin
    `uvm_info("my_randomize_int", "No max constraint, using default value", UVM_LOW)
      max = 2147483647;  
      end
      if(min == null) begin
    `uvm_info("my_randomize_int", "No min constraint, using default value", UVM_LOW)
      min= -2147483647;  
      end  
      mem = ($urandom(seed) % (max-min+1)) + min;    
   endfunction: my_randomize_int
```

I got the following error:
 Cannot compare type 'int' to type 'null':  It is illegal to compare a handle with a packed type.

I have to check if it's null because I want to display a mesage in case there is no value

Answer (score 0):

How about making the parameters `min` and `max` `longint`s and giving default values that are out of range of an `int`?

```
function void my_randomize_int(int seed, inout int mem, input longint min = -2147483648, longint max = 2147483648); 
  if(max == 2147483648) begin
    `uvm_info("my_randomize_int", "No max constraint, using default value", UVM_LOW)
    max = 2147483647;  
  end
  if(min == -2147483648) begin
    `uvm_info("my_randomize_int", "No min constraint, using default value", UVM_LOW)
    min= -2147483647;  
  end  
  mem = ($urandom(seed) % (max-min+1)) + min;    
endfunction: my_randomize_int
```

https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5_qB

Comment: I rather not, because I want to display a mesage in case there is no value.

Comment: @sara8d OK. Updated. You didn't specify that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

In SystemVerilog, you must pass a value to a function argument unless you have declared a default argument value

```
function void my_randomize_int(      int     seed, 
                               inout int     mem, 
                               input longint min = -2147483648, 
                                     longint max = 2147483648);
```

And if you do not pass a value to the min or max arguments, there is no way from inside the function to know if the default was used, or if the user happened to pass a value equal to the default. I would just assume they would never do that.

Comment: But I have to know if the user pass a value, because:
1.I want to display a mesage in case there is no value.
2. I have another function :
   `function void  my_randomize_vec_bit (inout bit [31:0] mem, input int seed, int size, int_type curr_int_type, int min, int max);`
Which do for example:
 `if (curr_int_type == SIGNED) begin
     max = 2 ** (size-1) -1;     
  end
  else begin
     max = (2 ** size ) - 1;     
  end`

Comment: I''ll repeat:  there is no way from inside the function to know if the default was used, or if the user happened to pass a value equal to the default.

Answer (score 0):

An `int`, like other numerical data types, cannot be `null`. Also, they way your function header is defined, `min` and `max` must be despaired in the methods call or it will be a compiling error.

To resolve this, `min` and `max` need to declared as `integer` and have a default value of `'x`. Then use the `$isunknown` system function to determine if the `min` and `max` have legal values.

```
function void my_randomize_int(int seed, inout int mem, integer min = 'x, integer max = 'x);
  if($isunknown(max)) begin
    `uvm_info("my_randomize_int", "No max constraint, using default value", UVM_LOW)
    max = 2147483647;
  end
  if($isunknown(min)) begin
    `uvm_info("my_randomize_int", "No min constraint, using default value", UVM_LOW)
    min= -2147483647;
  end
  mem = ($urandom(seed) % (max-min+1)) + min;    
endfunction: my_randomize_int
```

Another approach is to leave them as `int` and assign them with your min/max values. Be aware this approach will not let you check if the min/max constraint was given.

```
function void my_randomize_int(int seed, inout int mem, int min = -2147483647, int max = 2147483647);
```

FYI: you need to swap the values of `min` and `max` if min>max